# I want to participate in linux kernel development, where can i find some what is needed to do?

Tags: linux-kernel, c, development

I want to participate in linux kernel development but i don't have idea what, in technically meaning i can do (i am looking for tasks). I am experienced C programmer, i know some linux kernel, i have some experience in simple driver writing, some modifications for my own purpose in kernel drivers.I am looking for some TODO list, someone who will propose me a task.

I know about mailing list, but the main list is too big.

Maybe some internet forum, irc channel something like that.

Comment: This is a laudable (commendable) goal, but I don't know that it's on topic for this site in its current form.  Also, did you try Google?  A quick search for "linux kernel development" points to https://kernelnewbies.org as a possible starting point.

Comment: Yes i tried. I am looking for something that is not easy searchable - something that is obvious for someone involved in linux development process. I know kernel newbies.

Comment: I'd start looking at [kernel bug tracker](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/)

Comment: The question is on topic, can we reopen it please?

Answer (score 4):

As you already know [kernelnewbies.org](http://kernelnewbies.org), there is also a kernelnewbies irc chan (on OFTC).

You can check in the staging directory, here are drivers that need cleanup or improvements, some have a TODO list.

You can also use tools like sparse, to find bugs to fix.

You can also look at [Eudyptula-challenge](http://eudyptula-challenge.org/) which is very good introduction in kernel developement. It's not currently accepting applicants, but may be back in the future.